# In how many ways $2$ bananas can be distributed among $5$ persons if each person can get any number of things?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> In how many ways $2$ bananas can be distributed among $5$ persons if each person can get any number of things?

Is my solution correct and is there any general formula?

Let the bananas be $B$ and $B$. Let the persons be $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5$

**Now let's form cases**

Case $1$: **when two persons get a banana each**

$P_1P_2,P_1P_3,P_1P_4,P_1P_5,P_2P_3,P_2P_4,P_2P_5,P_3P_4,P_3P_5,P_4P_5$ Total $10$ cases

Case $2:$ **when only one person gets a banana**

$P_1$ or $P_2$ or $P_3$ or $P_4$ or $P_5$ Total $5$ cases

Case $3:$ **when only one person gets $2$ bananas**

$P_1$ or $P_2$ or $P_3$ or $P_4$ or $P_5$ Total $5$ cases

Case $4:$ **when no person gets a banana**

$1$ case

So, in total there are $21$ cases. Is it right$?$ Is there a general formula for these types of questions$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have answered the question: In how many ways can up to two indistinguishable bananas be distributed to five people without restriction?  Was that your intention?

Comment: I suspect that *all* bananas must be given to some person. If I am right in this then the cases 2 and 4 fall out and you can recognize the problem as one that can be solved with [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). This can also be used if I am wrong but then there are $3$ cases to look at: 2, 1 or 0 bananas are handed over.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig i thought all bananas are same ...the thing that matters in the numbers

Comment: Assuming the bananas are indistinguishable, I also would have interpreted the problem to mean that both bananas are distributed to five people.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig so what are the total number of cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting the question as follows:

> In how many ways can two indistinguishable bananas be distributed to five people without restriction?

Note that interpretation corresponds to your cases 1 and 3, as drhab pointed out in the comments.

**Method 1:**  Since there are only two bananas, there are two possibilities: one person receives both bananas, which can occur in five ways, or two people each receive one banana, which can occur in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, giving
$$\binom{5}{1} + \binom{5}{2} = 15$$
possibilities.

This method does not generalize well when there are many bananas to distribute.  Let's examine the method drhab suggested in the comments.

**Method 2:**  Let $x_i$ be the number of bananas the $i$th person receives.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 2 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation $1$ in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of $5 - 1 = 4$ addition signs in a row of two ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 + + + +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2, x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = 0$, while
$$+ 1 + + 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 1, x_3 = 0, x_4 = 1, x_5 = 0$.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can place four addition signs in a row of two ones, which is
$$\binom{2 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{6}{4} = 15$$
since we must choose which $5 - 1 = 4$ of $2 + 5 - 1 = 6$ positions required for two ones and four addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

The number of ways $k$ bananas could be distributed to $n$ people without restriction is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k \tag{2}$$
in the nonnegative integers.  The number of solutions of equation $2$ in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ bananas in a row of $k$ ones, which is
$$\binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1}$$
since we must choose which $n - 1$ of the $k + n - 1$ positions required for $k$ ones and $n - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Comment: Mr. Taussig, you forgot the case "one person gets zero bananas".

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  I said at the outset that I was interpreting the problem to mean that two indistinguishable bananas were being distributed to the five people, so I did not consider cases where fewer than two bananas were being distributed.  If I had, I would have obtained $21$ possible distributions there is one way to distribute no bananas to five people (do nothing) and five ways to distribute one banana to five people.  Using my first method, the answer would have become $\binom{5}{0} + \binom{5}{1} + \binom{5}{1} + \binom{5}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

1. There are 5 initial choices, and for each of them there are other 5 choices for the 2nd banana. So we have 25 possible ways to draw bananas.
2. But P1 & P2 is the same as P2 & P1, so we need to subtract those. For P1 there are 4 duplicates which we remove, then for P2 there are other 4, but we subtracted one already, so 3 left and so on.

**Eventually** it's going to be: $5^2 - (4 + 3 + 2 + 1) = 15$.

In case number of people is large, it's possible to simplify the sum using [the famous riddle about counting the sum of 1 to 100](https://byjus.com/question-answer/find-the-sum-of-all-natural-number-from-1-to-100/) which would give us: $5^2 - 5\times2=15$.